# Valid after submit not call code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

i need to submit a form before call another one..

i have this:

```
$('#Add_New').unbind("click").on("click", function (evt) {
        $("#frmNew").validate();

        if ($("#frmNew").valid()) {
            $("#frmNew").submit();
            var urlNew = $('#pollUrl').data('url-new-question');
            location.href = urlNew;
        }
    });
```

my form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PollNew", "Poll", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "frmNew" }))
```

but it not call the C# code behind for submit..
how can i do this?

Comment: `$("#frmNew").get(0).submit();` ???

Comment: nothing.. it do the validation but on submit it not call the method

Comment: and if i remove the $("#frmNew").valid() and left only the submit it work..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here....

```
$('#Add_New').unbind("click").on("click", function (evt) {
    $("#frmNew").validate();

    if ($("#frmNew").valid()) {
        $("#frmNew").submit();
        var urlNew = $('#pollUrl').data('url-new-question');
        location.href = urlNew;
    }
});
```

However, I can tell you that `.validate()` is the *initialization* method of the plugin and does not get called inside of a `click()` event handler.  It most typically gets called *once* within the DOM Ready event handler to initialize the validation plugin on your form along with your defined rules & options.

Secondly, you do **not** need to programatically check to see if the form is valid and manually call `.submit()`.  That's what the `submitHandler` callback function is for... it's only called when the form is valid and submits the form automatically at that time.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // stuff to do when the form is valid.
    // you can use ajax to submit the data here
    // then do something else
}
```

And finally, I don't know how you're going to do a `.submit()` and then a subsequent `location.href`... the normal submit action of the form is going to redirect to a new page *before* the `location.href` can do anything.